# The result not found message displays with the searched data

Tags: javascript

```js
 <script>

 function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, occurrence;

      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("helpseekers");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
         occurrence = false; // Only reset to false once per row.
         td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
         for(var j=0; j< td.length; j++){                
             currentTd = td[j];
             if (currentTd ) {
                 if (currentTd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                     tr[i].style.display = "";
                     occurrence = true;
                 } 
             }
         }
         if(!occurrence){
             tr[i].style.display = "none";
         $('#error4').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;" align="center">No results found</p>');
           window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
         } 
     }
   }
</script>
```

This is the code for searching and displaying data from a table.The searching works well but it shows  "No result found message " with the searched result even though the searched data in the table.I got the searched data with the no result found message.I need the warning message "no result found" only when the searched result not in the table.

Comment: Hi Ashi, in my opinion you should simplify the snippet in your question. The less peripheral code, the better. In your code you are simply having trouble with an algorithm -- so the extraneous HTML part of your context should not be exposed to the forum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a different flag to check if search keyword is found in table or not. `occurrence` is used to hide and display the table row based on search keyword. So you can use another variable to print the "No Result found".

Posting the edited code here. I added one boolean var `found` as a flag to search query.

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, occurrence, found=false;

      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("helpseekers");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
         occurrence = false; // Only reset to false once per row.
         td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
         for(var j=0; j< td.length; j++){                
             currentTd = td[j];
             if (currentTd ) {
                 if (currentTd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                     tr[i].style.display = "";
                     occurrence = true;
                     found = true;
                 } 
             }
         }

        if(!occurrence){
             tr[i].style.display = "none";
         } 

     }

    if(!found){
         $('#error4').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;" align="center">No results found</p>');
           window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
    } 
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging purely from the code you provided, it seems like for every table row as long as there is one no occurrence, the No results found message pops up and the page gets reloaded after 3 seconds. If you want to only show that when all the table rows have no occurrence, try this code below. It is not tested so it may or may not work.

Basically what I have done is to add a `counter` that will increment everytime the if block goes into `!occurrence`. So if it matches the `tr.length`, then it means every table row did have no occurrence and then only then show the not found message.

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, occurrence;
  var counter = 0;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("helpseekers");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     occurrence = false; // Only reset to false once per row.
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
     for(var j=0; j< td.length; j++){                
         currentTd = td[j];
         if (currentTd ) {
             if (currentTd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                 tr[i].style.display = "";
                 occurrence = true;
             } 
         }
     }
     if(!occurrence){
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
         counter++;
     } 
 }
     if(counter === tr.length){
           $('#error4').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;" align="center">No results found</p>');
       window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The displaying of "No Result Found" should be taken outside the main loop (the loop over the rows).
Otherwise you will display "No Result Found" once for every single row that does not match.
Also, the `occurrence` flag should not be reset at each row, if in the end you want to determine that there was some rows found.